# Cosmos: DISTINCT results with JOIN and ORDER BY

Tags: azure, distinct, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to write a query that uses a `JOIN` to perform a geo-spatial match against locations in a array. I got it working, but added `DISTINCT` in order to de-duplicate (**Query A**):

```
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE
    u
FROM
    u
JOIN loc IN u.locations
WHERE
    ST_WITHIN(
        {'type':'Point','coordinates':[loc.longitude,loc.latitude]},
        {'type':'Polygon','coordinates':[[[-108,-43],[-108,-40],[-110,-40],[-110,-43],[-108,-43]]]})
```

However, I then found that combining `DISTINCT` with continuation tokens isn't supported unless you also add `ORDER BY`:

```
System.ArgumentException: Distict query requires a matching order by in order to return a continuation token. If you would like to serve this query through continuation tokens, then please rewrite the query in the form 'SELECT DISTINCT VALUE c.blah FROM c ORDER BY c.blah' and please make sure that there is a range index on 'c.blah'.
```

So I tried adding `ORDER BY` like this (**Query B**):

```
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE
    u
FROM
    u
JOIN loc IN u.locations
WHERE
    ST_WITHIN(
        {'type':'Point','coordinates':[loc.longitude,loc.latitude]},
        {'type':'Polygon','coordinates':[[[-108,-43],[-108,-40],[-110,-40],[-110,-43],[-108,-43]]]})
ORDER BY
    u.created
```

The problem is, the `DISTINCT` no longer appears to be taking effect because it returns, for example, the same record twice.

To reproduce this, create a single document with this data:

```
{
    "id": "b6dd3e9b-e6c5-4e5a-a257-371e386f1c2e",
    "locations": [
        {
            "latitude": -42,
            "longitude": -109
        },
        {
            "latitude": -42,
            "longitude": -109
        }
    ],
    "created": "2019-03-06T03:43:52.328Z"
}
```

Then run **Query A** above. You will get a single result, despite the fact that both locations match the predicate. If you remove the `DISTINCT`, you'll get the same document twice.

Now run **Query B** and you'll see it returns the same document twice, despite the `DISTINCT` clause.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Reproduced your issue indeed,based on my researching,it seems a defect in cosmos db `distinct` query. Please refer to this link:[Provide support for DISTINCT](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6719531-provide-support-for-distinct).

> This feature is broke in the data explorer. Because cosmos can only
>   return 100 results per page at a time, the distinct keyword will only
>   apply to a single page. So, if your result set contains more than 100
>   results, you may still get duplicates back - they will simply be on
>   separately paged result sets.

You could describe your own situation and vote up this feedback case.